# Application of geometric probability

Tags: probability

Given that $0< a,b <75$, how can I find the probability $P(|a-b|\leq 30)$ using geometric probability?  (Note that $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, not constrained to the integers.)

How I approached this question:

total number of outcomes $= 74 \times 74$ and favourable outcomes
$= 74+2(73+72+71+\cdots + 44)$

But the answer is not correct

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91373/discussion-on-question-by-kshitij-singh-application-of-geometric-probability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shaded area is the favourable area of your event where the total area of the box is $75^2$ sq. units. Whereas the shaded area is $3600$ sq. units. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take $(a,b)$ as coordinates in 2-d plane and find the number of points using geometry whose coordinate difference is less than or equal to $30$.
You should be fine for till $(31,31)$ square. Take a strip of points around the square. You would need to avoid 2 points $(32,1)$ and $(1,32)$. Likewise 4 in next strip. Hope this helps.
I assume probability is of finding or not finding favorable points in the given  area.